# Instantiating ExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I read that one can not create an instance of an interface in Java but in the following code, `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` returns an `ExecutorService` Instance despite the fact that `ExecutorService` is an interface:

```
//WorkerThread is a class that implements Runnable
WorkerThread worker = new WorkerThread();
Executor exec=Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
exec.execute(worker);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create an instance of an interface, but you can certainly create an instance of a class that implements that interface.

`Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` returns an instance of the class `FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService`, which implements the `ExecutorService` interface.

```
public static ExecutorService newSingleThreadExecutor() {
    return new FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService
        (new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1,
                                0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When a class implements some interface it can be instantiated as that interface.

```
interface TheInterface {}
class Test implements TheInterface {}

...

TheInterface test = new Test();
```

Answer (score 0):

`ExecutorService` is an interface and extends `Executor` which is also an interface which expose some method .For an example in your case you can when you are calling `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` it is returning instance of `ThreadPoolExecutor` which implementing Executor so you can write .

```
Executor executor=Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

and you can call only method available on Executor interface i.e `execute(Runnable command)` on that interface.

For an interface you can not directly create using interface

```
Executor executor =new  Executor();//Not possible
```

It is a best practice refer using interface so you can change implementation without changing your code